# Не обновляются размеры у Renderer

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я написал скрипт в котором после изменения localScale у объекта хочу получить значения bounds, но renderer не меняет значения bounds, как решить эту проблему?

Скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestSize : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject obj;
        public Renderer objRenderer;

        void Start()
        {
            obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(4, 4, 4);

            Debug.Log(objRenderer.bounds.extents.x);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а ты уверен что не меняет ??
у меня всё меняет

```
public class TestSize : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    public Renderer objRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("do: " + objRenderer.bounds.extents.x);

        obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(4f, 4f, 4f);

        Debug.Log("posle: " + objRenderer.bounds.extents.x);
    }


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, а мне приходилось получать GetComponet заново

Comment: Я понял в чём причина, я использовал Instantiate и префаб  и renderer тоже с префаба брал, из-за этого не меняется!